# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Why this error : Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.0.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

on Latest Android Studio
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841, built on April 19, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0

I am behind the proxy